# Mongoose Find All then find all in other schema for each

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

in my application i need to find Categories, then i want Books for this Categories

```
const CategorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    displayname: String,
    category: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);

}

const BookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    img: String,
    category: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category'
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Books', BookSchema);
```

i need a response like this

```
categories = [
 {
  category: 'News',
  books: [{name:'',id''},{}..]
 },
 {
  category: 'Sports',
  books: [{name:'',id''},{}..]
 }
];
```

so my code looks like this

```
Router.get('/categories/', (req, res) => {
    Category.find({}, (err, categories) => {
        Promise.all(categories.map(category => {
            return Book.find({category: category._id}).then( books => {
                return {
                    category: category,
                    books: books
                };
            })
        })).then( categories => {
            res.json(categories);
        })
    })
});
```

please some one know if have better solution for this query?
thanks all!

Comment: you can use `populate`. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: again i do not get all categories and their books in your example, i get only 1 category with their books

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deep populate on mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255313/how-to-deep-populate-on-mongoose)

Comment: @iagowp is not deep populate :\ i hope that was my solution.

Comment: Ok @Alin, can you show us what answer you are getting from that code?

Comment: Oh, I understood what you want now. I dont think there`s a better way to do that, your DB is just poorly structured for the query you want to do. You should have an array of book ids that belong in that category on the category, instead referencing the category on the book

Comment: Ok, then if i create a book, i should save Book.save and then update Category array? every time?

Comment: Either that, or keep it the way you are doing. I honestly don't know what is better, I guess it depends on how you are going to use it (do you save/delete lots of books? or you create a few, but search them all the time?). I've used both ways, and I prefer the way you did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
Router.get('/categories/', (req, res) => {
  Book.find().populate('category').then( books => {
    var categories = {}
    for(var i = 0; i <  books.length; i++){
      categories[books[i].category.displayname] = {
        category: books[i].category.displayname
        books: categories[books[i].category.displayname].books ? categories[books[i].category.displayname].books.push(books[i]) : [books[i]]
      };
    }
    var result = [];
    for(var key in categories){
      result.push(categories[key])
    }
    return result;
  });
});
```

It could be prettier, but it only makes one request to your db and should work the way you want

Comment: it nice answer, i want to know if mongoose expose api for this scenario, like 'populate'.

Comment: What you mean by expose api?

Comment: i mean that have official solution , example for populate you can use promises and for loops and get same results but mongoose use populate method for this scenario, so i ask if they have official method for my scenario

Answer (score 0):

From http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

```
Book.
  find({}).
  populate('category').
  exec(function (err, story) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    // Do other things
  });
```

Comment: again i do not get all categories and their books in your example, i get only 1 category with their books

Comment: Category.
  find({ category: category._id }).
  populate('books').
  exec(function (err, story) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    // Do other things
  }); , it won't work because on category schema do not have refernce for books